# Print log message immediately when they occured in catel

Tags: logging, catel

I want to display the logmessages directly when they occurred.

```
public void MyMethod()
{
  _log.Info("Start of MyMethod");

  //.. Do a lot of things

  _log.Info("End of MyMethod");
}
```

I add a log listener to show the logmessages on screen. But both logmessages are displayd if the method is ended. Is it possible to display logmessages directly when they occurred.

Answer (score 0):

This is very complex, and I will try to explain why it works like this. Imagine the method running in a background thread. Then the messages *must be dispatched* to the UI thread. There are 2 ways we can dispatch:

- BeginInvoke (put at the end of the queue)
- Invoke (do it now)

Using `Invoke` might look good here, but it will block the (background) thread until the UI thread has returned. If the UI-thread is also waiting for something, you have a deadlock.

The safest way is to use BeginInvoke (what Catel uses). If a listener supports multithreading, it will be handled immediately, otherwise it will be flushed in batches for performance (for example, files will be flushed in batches of 50 or 100).

Comment: Ok. So it makes no sense to log the begin of the method. Only print the success or fail of the method.

Comment: It makes sense because it will still log in the right order. It's just not as real-time as you wish.